# Bash script to validate a MySQL database

Tags: beginner, mysql, bash, linux, shell

I am fairly new to bash script programming so I would love some feedback.
I am trying to write a series of migration scripts for our DBs (please don't direct me to other tools; I spent a lot of time evaluating them and am forced to write custom code) and this is script that contains validation logic.

Basic requirements:

1. Validate file format.
2. Make sure the script exists in at least 1 descriptor. A descriptor dictates the scripts to execute and in which order. If a release file isn't in a descriptor it's inert so validate it's present
3. ensure a corresponding rollback exists
4. ensure a validation script exists
5. execute the validation script and verify results.

how I intend it (for now) to be used is

```
source ./validation.sh
validateFormat scripts/release/DBA-1234 || echo "fail"
```

as an example. Or this, which would apply all:

```
validate
```

ideally, I would love to be able to chain them together functionally but when I try the below, it doesn't seem to know my symbols:

> xargs: validateFormat: No such file or directory

```
find scripts/releases -name '*.sql' | xargs validateFormat | validateDescriptor | cat | mysql
```

or just

```
find scripts/releases -name '*.sql' | xargs validate | cat | mysql
```

release-format (DBA-1234_some_message.sql)

```
([A-Z]{2,5}[_-][0-9]{1,5})[_-]?(.*)
```

validation.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

user=root
password=my-secret-pw
port=3306
host=127.0.0.1
release_format=$(cat .utils/release-format)
releases=${scripts}/releases/
validators=${scripts}/validators/
descriptors=${scripts}/descriptors/
rollbacks=${scripts}/rollbacks/


validateDescriptor() {
  [[ -z $1 ]] && return -1 
  local script=$(basename $1)
  grep -rq ${script} ${descriptors};
  return $?
}


ensureRollback() {
  [[ -z $1 ]] && return -1
  ls ${rollbacks}/$(toTicket ${1})* 2>&1 >/dev/null
  return $?
}

ensureValidator() {
  [[ -z $1 ]] && return -1
  ls ${validators}/$(toTicket ${1})* 2>&1 >/dev/null
  return $?
}

validateFormat() {
  [[ -z $1 ]] && return -1
  [[ $(basename -s .sql $1) =~ ${release_format} ]] && return 0 || return -1
}


toTicket() {
  [[ -n $1 ]] && basename -s .sql ${1} | sed -E "s/$release_format/\1/"
}

toValidator() {
  [[ -z $1 ]] && return -1
  local ticket=$(toTicket ${1})
  local validator=$(ls ${validators}/${ticket}* | head -1)
  [[ $? != 0 ]] && return $? || echo ${validator}
}

applyValidationScripts() {
  [[ -z $1 ]] && return -1
  local validator=$(toValidator ${1})

  if [[ ! -e ${validator} ]]; then
    return -1
  fi

  result=$(mysql -sN -h ${host} -u ${user} -p${password} -P ${port} <${validator})
  if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    return $?
  fi

  if [[ $(echo ${result} | wc -l | tr -d ' ') != 1 ]]; then
    echo "validation result count was more than 1 row. Invalid results"
    return -1
  else
    return $((result - 1))
  fi
}

validate() {
  for release in $(find ${releases} -type f -exec basename -s .sql {} \;); do
    #  applyValidationScripts ${release}
    validateFormat ${release}  && ensureRollback ${release} && ensureValidator ${release} && validateDescriptor ${release}
    [[ $? != 0 ]] && echo "${release} failed validation"
  done;
}
```

Comment: `validateFormat` doesn't produce any output. I wonder how you can pipe it.

Comment: If I were you, I'd remove the description of how you fail to run under `xargs` when you fail to `export -f` the function - that makes it look like your code doesn't work, which would make it *not yet ready for review*.  The code itself *is* ready; you just need to go to Stack Overflow to [learn to use it more effectively](//stackoverflow.com/q/11003418).

Comment: @vnp I removed the output from validate format because I couldn't get it to chain.

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks for the insight. I will give this a try

Comment: I ran `export -f ` and it doesn't help. How should I post a code update?

Answer (score 3):

## Prefer portable shell

There's no reason to use Bash `[[` where `[` will do, unless you already depend on other Bash features (such as arrays).  This will of course increase the number of places where you must:

## Quote parameter expansions

In expansions like `$(basename -s .sql $1)`, don't forget the quotes:

```
[[ $(basename -s .sql "$1") =~ ${release_format} ]]
# I removed `&& return 0 || return -1` - see next item
```

## Let exit status flow naturally

The Bash manual says:

> When executed, the exit status of a function is the exit status of the last command executed in the body.

This means that adding `return $?` to the end of every function adds no value, as do constructs such as `&& return 0 || return -1` - just let success/fail flow through.

## Put credentials in a separate file

Don't put `user` and `password` in the script (particularly if you want to put it into a version control server).  Instead, require each user to provide their credentials in a (non-world-readable) file.  If you're particularly diligent, you could fail the script if the permissions on the credentials file are too permissive.

## Don't invoke `ls` just to check existence

```
# true if the first argument exists
one_exists()
{
    test -e "$1"
}

ensureRollback() {
     test -n "$1" && one_exists "${rollbacks}/$(toTicket ${1})"*
}
```

Comment: Great suggestions, let me implement those.

Comment: What's the benefit of quoting "$1" ? That expands it. But it currently works too. So, what benefit is it? I just don't know the difference

Comment: re: passwords - these credentials are for a docker container used for test. It's of no consequence and they can be overriden. I intend to have this script sourced into a build which takes commandline args which would include these variables. for the release process I will consider the password file. For build: It just complicates something where username and pass are totally optional

Comment: If parameters are expanded outside of quotes, the result is subject to  [word splitting and pathname expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).  Quoted strings are preserved as single words by the above; this will reduce the incidence of surprises.  (Even if you *know* you'll never get spaces in the value, there's no harm to using quotes, and it signals to the reader that you're aware of the issue).